# Word for "not putting thought into something"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm writing a letter to someone and I want to describe the way a woman talked to me the whole night.

Every time I told her something, I got short answers which had zero thought put into them. Like "oh really?" or "That's nice."

So what would be a good word that I can use to describe putting no thought into something (such as the way one responds)?

Comment: Was she disinterested or did she just have nothing interesting to add?

Comment: my guess would be "worried about the creepy stalker who won't take a hint and go away".

Comment: Maybe she was *elsewhere*. You haven't given enough information to describe her behaviour, as we don't know **why** she behaved in this *lacklustre* way. Maybe she was preoccupied, maybe she was uninterested, maybe she was deliberately being rude, maybe simply tired, drunk or stupid.

Comment: , <- you dropped this

Comment: Downvoted because of lack of context.  It's one thing if you were two strangers sitting next to each other on a long flight and another if you were both guests at a mutual friend's dinner party.

Comment: Unthoughtfully? Yeah, I didn't put thought into that.

Comment: @Shaniya You sure you weren't being thoughtless?

Answer (score 48):

The situation you're describing doesn't so much sound like she was putting no thought into her answers, as that she *didn't want to have the conversation*, and therefore was deliberately not engaging with the conversation, perhaps to send you a signal to stop talking to her.

This style of conversation would be described as ***dismissive***

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dismissive

Comment: Aka: *smile and nod your head*.

Comment: @Mazura that's the best advice I learned from my father for dealing with people to whom I don't want to listen.

Answer (score 45):

**perfunctory**

> adjective
>
> 1. performed merely as a routine duty; hasty and superficial:
>    *perfunctory courtesy*.
> 2. lacking interest, care, or enthusiasm; indifferent or apathetic:
>    *In his lectures he reveals himself to be merely a perfunctory speaker*.
>
> [[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/perfunctory)]

Answer (score 25):

You could describe her as **absent**, and as responding **absently**.

> **[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/absent)**: (3) showing that a person is thinking about something else :
>   showing a lack of attention to what is happening or being said.

Answer (score 15):

I thought of **curt**, but I liked **perfunctory** and **dismissive** too - excellent suggestions.

curt
/kərt/
(adjective)

rudely brief.

"his reply was curt"

synonyms:   terse, brusque, abrupt, clipped, blunt, short, monosyllabic, summary;

Answer (score 14):

The term to use somewhat depends on the state of the listener. If she was concentrating on something else, I would go with "**Distracted**". If not concentrating on something else, but also not concentrating on your comments or questions, I would think "**Mindless**" or "**Disengaged**". "**Absentminded**" would also fit in this case. Finally, if concentrating on your comments and questions, but finding them not worth her time to fully consider (for whatever reason), then "**Dismissive**" would fit.

Comment: +1 for disengaged. I definitely got the impression from the question that she was disengaged.

Comment: I was thinking along these lines, and I would add **preoccupied** and **inattentive** to your list.

Answer (score 8):

Disinterested, unengaged, and distracted all seem to describe this fairly well. Inconsiderate literally applies, too.

I also like thoughtless.

Since she wasn't thinking about the interaction, she clearly wasn't interested, invested, or engaged. Any terms along those lines, such as those above, apply.

Comment: Uninterested seems appropriate, but traditionally disinterested means unbiased rather than not interested.

Comment: The "no competeing interests" definition is neither more traditional, nor dramatically more common. It literally means both in current and historic use. (prescriptive advice, notwithstanding) http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/disinterested

Comment: Note, I'm not disagreeing that uninterested applies, nor that many would consider it superior, here; I'm only countering the "traditionally...means" which is inaccurate, albeit moderately so. That *is* the listed preferred sense according to OEDo and M-W but they both list both.

Answer (score 8):

**Offhand** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/offhand)

> *adjective* Ungraciously or offensively nonchalant or cool in manner
>
> *"you were a bit offhand with her this afternoon"*
>   *"Whatever, I dismissed him in an offhanded manner.*
>
> *adverb* Without previous thought or consideration
>
> *"I can’t think of a better answer offhand"*
>   *"Lessig treats this opposing view rather offhandedly, a serious flaw in an otherwise excellent book"*

Answer (score 4):

I know this is kind of obvious but what about

thoughtless?

Comment: From my experience, this word has a connotation to selfishness. Might just be me, though.

Comment: This definitely answers the question in the title.

Comment: Please explain your answer in full.

Answer (score 4):

You could describe the woman (or her remarks) as [vapid](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3A%20vapid):

> offering nothing that is stimulating or challenging.
>
> "tuneful but vapid musical comedies"
>
> *synonyms:*   insipid, uninspired, colorless, uninteresting, feeble, flat,
>   dull, boring, tedious, tired, unexciting, uninspiring, unimaginative,
>   uninvolving, lifeless, tame, vacuous, bland, trite, jejune

Answer (score 2):

From the posts above, I like perfunctory the best, but vacant could also apply. It has sort of a double meaning in that the person giving the reply is not there, and as a consequence the comments are also devoid of reflection.

Answering question strictly asked: No thought before answering could also be described as spontaneous or unfiltered, but those don't seem to fit the context.

Answer (score 2):

If she seemed disinterested or bored, I would consider **blasé**:

> Having or showing a lack of excitement or interest in something especially because it is very familiar
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster: Blasé](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blas%C3%A9)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

This would be called a "courtesy response."  One or two word replies such that someone doesn't want to appear to be rude, but are not entirely interested in carrying a conversation.

Answer (score 0):

How about **"superficial"**? This could explain both lack of engagement and knowledge.

Edit as per Sven's comment:

> Merriam-Webster, for example, suggests three definitions of *superficial* that might apply: "lying on, not penetrating below, or affecting only the surface"; "concerned only with with the obvious or apparent: SHALLOW"; and "presenting only an appearance without substance or significance."

Comment: This is a good word suggestion, but if you imagine that the person who asked the question may not be entirely familiar with the word _superficial_ in the relevant sense, you'll see why your answer would be better if you included a suitable dictionary definition as it applies to the poster's situation. Merriam-Webster, for example, suggests three definitions of _superficial_ that might apply: "lying on, not penetrating below, or affecting only the surface"; "concerned only with with the obvious or apparent: SHALLOW"; and "presenting only an appearance without substance or significance."

Comment: This is the word *she* would use, not him. I would have used *idgaf*.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a perfect match for the situation you experienced,
but, if the person were a bit more *engaged* in the conversation
(i.e., hearing what you were saying, but not caring),
you might call her attitude [***patronizing***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/patronizing):

> To treat in a condescending manner,
>   often in showing interest or kindness that is insincere

Answer (score 0):

I really like the aforementioned suggestion of **inattentive**.

For me, **distant** came to mind as well:

> **(of a person) not intimate; cool or reserved.**
>
> "his children found him strangely distant"
>
> **synonyms:** aloof, reserved, remote, detached, unapproachable; withdrawn, reticent, taciturn, uncommunicative, undemonstrative,
> unforthcoming, unresponsive, unfriendly

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Though it has connotations of meaning "without regard to someone's feelings", the word "thoughtless" is perfect here. Some will say this is old-fashioned, and because of today's usage, might be misinterpreted. I would contend that it is still the word of choice, despite any ignorance associated with it's meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the best way to describe her actions were **cavalier**

> cavalier
>
> > adj given to haughty disregard of others
> >
> > https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/cavalier

Answer (score -2):

[impulsive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Impulsive)

> Acting without giving much thought.
>
> doing things or tending to do things suddenly and without careful thought.
>
> done suddenly and without planning : resulting from a sudden impulse.